# mapDispatchToProps, id is not defined in action

Tags: react-native, redux

I get **id is not defined** in `fetchEvents`, when trying to use `button.value` as a parameter.

I am using `mapDispatchToProps` and `mapStateToProps` in my component.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    resetForm: () => dispatch(resetForm()),
    fetchEvents: setSubCategory => dispatch(fetchEvents(id))
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    setCredentials: state.setCredentials,
    categories: state.fetchCategories,
    isLoading: state.isLoading
  };
};
```

I then destructure my props to get my `id`:

```
const {
  fetchEvents,
  resetForm,
  isLoading,
  setCredentials: { setStudent, setGroup, setYear }
} = this.props;

const id = setStudent || setGroup || setYear;
```

However, when I dispatch my action:

```
 const buttonOptions = [
      {
        key: 0,
        label: "refresh",
        value: Id,
        icon: "undo"
      },
      {
        key: 1,
        label: "back",
        value: Id,
        icon: "caret-left"
      }
    ];

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {buttonOptions.map((button, i) => {
          const style =
            i == 0 ? styles.divContainerLeft : styles.divContainerRight;

          return (
            <View style={style} key={"view" + i}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                disabled={isLoading ? true : false}
                key={"TouchableOpacity" + i}

                // dispatch action here
                onPress={i == 0 ? () => fetchEvents(button.value) : resetForm}
              >
                <Icon
                  name={button.icon}
                  style={styles.button}
                  color="white"
                  key={"icon" + i}
                  size={30}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `mapDispatchToProps`, you are re-declaring the parameter name to `setSubCategory`, yet, in your fetch call you pass `id`.

Instead, try this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    resetForm: () => dispatch(resetForm()),
    fetchEvents: (setSubCategory) => dispatch(fetchEvents(setSubCategory))
  };
};
```

OR

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    resetForm: () => dispatch(resetForm()),
    fetchEvents: (id) => dispatch(fetchEvents(id))
  };
};
```

This is because you are declaring and inlining `fetchEvents` as an anonymous function. The parameter names must match.